# Uncaught Error: no such method 'show' for tooltip widget instance

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using ajax to submit a form for my registration, but am having an issue trying to setup tooltips to display error messages for errors that come back from the controller.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.user_modal_form', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  var context;
  context = $(this);
  if (data.success) {
    $('button', context).hide();
    $('.spinner', context).show();
    location.reload();
  } else {
    if (data.errors != null) {
      $.each(data.errors, function(key, error) {
        var field;
        field = $("#athlete_" + key);
        field.attr('data-original-title', "" + key + " " + error).tooltip({
          trigger: 'manual'
        }).tooltip("show");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Error Message: `Uncaught Error: no such method 'show' for tooltip widget instance`

Comment: Just came across this when trying to solve a similar problem, but I think the reason you were getting the error is that 'show' is an option and not a method, so the context for it would be:  `}).tooltip("option","show");`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I had the same error, which was a conflict with jQuery UI.

If you use jQuery UI then you need to reorder your script load order.

My working load order:

- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- Bootstrap

Comment: Perfect! Any suggestions how to go about this if Bootstrap is being loaded in a parent template? Is there a way to selectively ignore the tooltip library of jQuery UI?

Comment: I had a similar problem, scripts were in the correct order but I was deferring the jquery-ui script.

Answer (score 6):

The **root** of this and similar problem

> "no such method 'hide' for tooltip widget instance"

that both JqueryUI and Boostrap have **tooltip** method,

**JqueryUI** works like:

```
$el.tooltip("option","show");
$el.tooltip("option","hide");
```

**Boostrap** works like:

```
$el.tooltip("show");
$el.tooltip("hide");
```

So, as *Bogdan Lewis* showed you need to reorder your scripts, for example with **requirejs**, you need to make **Boostrap** be loaded after **JqueryUI**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery_ui');
require('bootstrap');
```

and adjust **config** for requirejs like:

```
    bootstrap: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery_ui']
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution for me was just to remove the *tooltips* components from the jQuery UI distribution I [downloaded](https://jqueryui.com/download/).

Answer (score 1):

It's a conflict between Bootstrap tooltip and jQuery tooltip

Let try, pls notice their load order:

```
<script src='/jQuery.js'></script>
<script src='/jQuery-ui.js'></script>
<script>
    $.fn.uitooltip = $.fn.tooltip;
</script>
<script src='/Bootstrap.js'></script>
<script>
    $.fn.bttooltip = $.fn.tooltip;
</script>
```

=> Now, instead of using "$.fn.tooltip" you can use "$.fn.uitooltip" to call the jQuery tooltip and "$.fn.bttooltip" to call the Bootstrap tooltip:

```
$('.uitooltip').uitooltip(); //jQuery
$('.bttooltip').bttooltip(); //Bootstrap
```